# "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" error in many to many & one to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I got following configuration:

```
public class Person
{
    // some default values

    public ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    // some default values

    public ICollection<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
}
```

Configuration in EF Core

```
builder.Entity<Persons>()
       .HasMany(r => r.Locations)
       .WithMany(l => l.Persons)
       .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                       b => b.HasOne<Location>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("LocationId"),
                       b => b.HasOne<Person>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("PersonId"))
       .ToTable("LocationPersonTable");
```

I had one to one relationship but now I want to add many to many, but I want to leave this one to many relation values, is that possible?

With the current implementation, I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LocationId', table 'MyDb.dbo.LocationPersonTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Do you have a [mre]? How do you insert values? Also what `public int? LocationId { get; set; }` on `Person` is supposed to mean, do you have one-2-many relationship between entities also?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you're trying to set up a many to many between Person and Location, but you're also trying to add an FK to Location *within* Person. You're overcomplicating the design a bit. If we can adjust the design to use a many to many with a more streamlined design, I think this will also take care of your error as a biproduct.

Do this:

1. Remove LocationId from the Person class.
2. Update your EF Core config:

   builder.Entity()
   .HasMany(p => p.Locations)
   .WithMany(l => l.Persons)
   .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
   "LocationPersonTable",
   b => b.HasOne().WithMany().HasForeignKey("LocationId"),
   b => b.HasOne().WithMany().HasForeignKey("PersonId"));

You'll need to create a migration to apply these changes, so make sure you have a backup of your db or if it's just test data, clear it out so you don't run into migration errors. Do not forget to backup your data if you're doing a migration and don't want to lose data. Because this migration will drop the LocationId from the Person table, and create the LocationPersonTable with the correct foreign key relationships.

Let me know if you have any questions. Here is [solid documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many) to further explain.

Comment: I can't remove location id because it is used in another places ;/

Comment: You shouldn't be using the LocationId from the Person entity, you should be using the LocationId from the Location entity. Then you will remove all of the references to LocationId from Person. Then, if you need to get to location from person, or to person from location, you use your join table LocationPersonTable